# Find Max in List Using Reduce Function

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def max_in_list(list):
    for value in list:
        reduce(maxof, list)
    print(list)
```

This program returns "reduce is not defined"
Can anyone explain the reduce function for me?

Comment: You need to import `functools` to use reduce: `from functools import reduce`

Comment: Also, don't use `list` as a variable name for your *list*. You are shadowing the built-in `list` and could face issues with your code.

Comment: Also, why are you reimplementing `max`?

Comment: In Python 3, `reduce` was removed from builtins. You can still find it in `functools`, though, as noted by idjaw. Also, you just call `reduce`, but you don't do anything with the result, and you should not do it within the loop. You probably want `return reduce(maxof, lst)`, or, well, just `return max(lst)`